# Small script letter 'f'

Tags: fonts

I am desperately trying to find the following 'script f' glyph (see below) to display on LaTeX but have been failing.

Which CTAN package should I install to get this character in math mode??

Many thanks!

[image: Script f sample]

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Perhaps not really the same, but this could work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,graphicx}
\usepackage{calligra}
\newcommand{\fancyf}{%
  \mkern-4mu
  \text{%
    \scalebox{1}[.8]{%
      \rotatebox[origin=c]{20}{\fontfamily{calligra}\selectfont f}
    }%
  }%
 \mkern-4mu
}

\begin{document}
The function $\fancyf_l(p)$
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, then

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont[range=\mathscr]{XITS Math}
\begin{document}
The function $\mathscr{f}_l(p)$
\end{document}
```

will produce

[image]

With Asana Math instead of XITS Math you get

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're aiming to use a Times (New) Roman text and math font that features a script-style lowercase-f symbol. One way to achieve this look is to use the [MathTime Professional 2 Fonts](http://www.pctex.com/mtpro2.html) package, along with a package such as `times` that provides a Times Roman text font. (An alernative to the `times` package is `newtxtext`.)

Note that the full `mtpro2` package isn't free of charge, and this thus not available from the CTAN. However, it's priced quite reasonably, especially when compared with some other packages that provide math fonts.

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}  
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{times}           % text font
\usepackage[mtpscr]{mtpro2}  % math font
\begin{document}  
function $\mathscr{f}_l(p)$
\end{document}
```